# Need to access a field present inside a private inner class

Tags: java, reflection, private-members

```
class OuterClass {
    // The below object will be initiated somewhere within
    private OuterClass.InnerClass innerClassObj;
    private class InnerClass {
        {
            int innerClassVariable;
        }
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         OuterClass outerClassObj = new OuterClass();
     }
}
```

I need to access the field 'innerClassvariable' present in 'InnerClass' Using 'innerClassObj' present in 'OuterClass' from 'SomeOtherClass'

Comment: @Pshemo , is there a way possible?

Comment: You scoped `innerClassVariable` with block scoping, it will not be visible outside of the `InnerClass`. It it as if you created a local variable inside a method... Remove the parentheses. Also, the variable has default scope, and may not be publicly available. Read about scoping and encapsulation.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl which parentheses i need to remove, sorry.

Comment: See my example below, I commented them out there.

Answer (score 0):

You scoped `innerClassVariable` with block scoping, it will not be visible outside of the `InnerClass`. It it as if you created a local variable inside a method...

1. Remove the (scope) parentheses.
2. Instantiate a new instance of the `InnerClass` inside `OuterClass`
3. Create a way to access the variable of the inner-class

```java
class OuterClass {
    private OuterClass.InnerClass innerClassObj;

    private class InnerClass {
        //{
            protected int innerClassVariable = 1; // Set to something...
        //}
    }

    public OuterClass() {
        this.innerClassObj = new InnerClass(); // Instantiate...
    }

    public int getInnerClassVariable() {
        return innerClassObj.innerClassVariable; // Have a way to access the value...
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OuterClass outerClassObj = new OuterClass();
        int value = outerClassObj.getInnerClassVariable();

        System.out.println(value); // 1
    }
}
```

Comment: No i am not allowed to modify the code present within **InnerClass** , I need to access it someway from outside, Thank You.